# Which pattern most closely matches scenario detailed and is it good practice?

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns, webforms

I have seen a particular pattern a few times over the last few years. Please let me describe it.

In the UI, each new record (e.g., new customers details) is stored on the form without saving to database. This clearly has been done so not clutter the database or cause unnecessary database hits.

While in the UI state, these objects are identified using a Guid. When these are a saved to the database, their associated Guids are not stored. Instead, they are assigned a database Int as their primary key.

The form can cope with a mixure of retrieved items from the database (using Int) as well as those that have not yet been committed (using Guid).

When inspecting the form (using Firebug) to see which key was used, we found a two part delimited combined key had been used. The first part is a guid (an empty guid if drawn from the database) and the second part is the integer (zero is stored if it is not drawn from the database). As one part of the combined key will always uniquely identify a record, it works rather well.

Is this Good practice or not? Can anyone tell me the pattern name or suggest one if it is not already named?

Comment: if you could provide little more details and clarity on your question to understand better. You had me at "When inspecting" line. :)

Comment: Oh yes, by "When inspecting", I meant inspecting a hidden field on the form with firebug. In the case, where record had not been retrieved from the database the field value would read for example, "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000,66". Whereas when a record already existed in the database it would show a value like "C4200000-0000-0000-0000-F00000000000,0".

Comment: which ASP.NET controls result in this markup?

Comment: Oh, it's just a ASP.Net DropDownList. These are examples of values, whereas the associated text shows a customer name. The value is split into a keyvaluepair which is stuffed into two properties, ID (Int32) and Identity (Guid).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple patterns at play here.

### [Identity Field Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityField.html)

Defined in P of EAA as "*Saves a database ID field in an object to maintain identity between an in-memory object and a database row.*"  This part is obvious.

### [Transaction Script](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/transactionScript.html) and [Metadata Mapping](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/metadataMapping.html)

In general, the ASP.NET DataBound controls use something like an **Transaction Script** pattern in conjunction with a **Metadata Mapping** pattern.  Fowler defines Metadata Mapping as "holding details of object-relational mapping in metadata".  If you have ever written a data source control, the Metadata Mapping aspect of this pattern seems obvious.

The **Transaction Script** pattern "organizes business logic by procedures where each procedure handles a single request from the presentation."  In order to encapsulate the logic of maintaining both presentation state and data-state it is necessary for the intermediary object to indicate:

1. If a database record exists
2. How to identify the backend data record, to populate the UI control
3. How to identify the data and the UI control if there is no current data record, so that presentation data can be updated from the backend datastore.

The presence of the new client data entry `Guid` and the data-record `integer` Id provide adequate information to determine all of this with only a single call to the database.  This could be accomplished by just using integers (and perhaps giving a unique negative integer for each unpersisted UI data item), but it is probably more explicit to have two separate fields.

## Good or Bad Practice?

It depends.  ASP.NET is a pretty successful software project, and this pattern seems to work consistently.  However, this type of ASP.NET web control has a very specific scope of application - to encapsulate interaction between a UI and a database about data objects with **simple mappings**.  The concerns do seem a little blurred, but for many applicable scenarios this will still be acceptable.  The pattern is valid whereever a [Row Data Gateway](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/rowDataGateway.html) would be acceptable.  If there is more than one database row affected by a web control, then this approach will not be functional.  In these more complex cases, either an [Active Record](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) implementation or the combination of a [Domain Model](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html) and a [Repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) implementation would be better suited.

**Whether a pattern is good or bad practice really depends on the scenario in which it is being applied.  It seems like people tend to advocate more complex design structures, because they can be applied to more scenarios without failing.**  However, in a very simple application where the mappings between data records and the UI are direct, this pattern is very useful because it creates the intended result while minimizing the amount of performance and development overhead.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of response I was after. It highlight the relations to patterns as well as not being critical of an pragmatic approach that works well.

Comment: @Carnotaurus, glad I could help.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a specific pattern for that.

Is it good practice? I don't think so. First, it's not very object oriented. How about:

```
interface ICommittable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the entity was already committed to the database.
    /// </summary>
    bool IsCommitted;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the ID of the entity, used either in database or generated by UI or an underlying BL.
    /// </summary>
    Guid Id;
}
```

Instead, what they do is to **mix three separate data entries in one** in a non obvious way:

- The ID
- Another ID (why?)
- A fact that the entity was committed or not.

Especially, having two separate IDs is extremely confusing and will require not only a good documentation, but some time for a new developer to understand what's happening here.

If the purpose was to create new entities without querying the database for a new ID, they could use GUIDs everywhere: when a new entity is created, you `Guid.CreateNew` it's ID, then, if need, you commit everything, this GUID being the identifier in the database too (there are few chances to have a collision between already saved GUIDs and a new one, so I wouldn't care about that).

Much more simple, isn't it?

It's also not easy to do a few things. For example, how do you compare two entities? Remember that:

- Two committed entities which have different GUIDs are not equal,
- Two not committed entities which have different IDs are not equal,
- A committed entity may be equal to a non committed entity, even if their GUIDs *and* their IDs *will* be different.

To conclude, **it seems like a lack of refactoring**. Probably they were modifying a project where entities were already identified in the database by their `id (int)` unique key, so instead of refactoring this, they just added GUIDs, thus making the overall thing:

- More difficult to understand,
- Very difficult to work with and to modify in future.

Comment: It needs the other ID to uniquely identify that it from IDs that have alreaddy been committed. I think using one ID of type Int would have been better than the original, where the sign of ID would determine if it had been committed or not.

Comment: @Carnotaurus: with a signed integer, it will be the same thing, with the same problems: you'll mix again three data entries into one, with all the issues I've described.

Comment: @Carnotaurus the whole point of using Guid is to ensure uniqueness across systems.

Comment: You can arbitrarily use Int or Guid types in this scenario. As EITHER can store a unique value.

Comment: I think you are a bit hasty to condemn this approach without understanding the business use case (which is impossible since the OP doesn't contain this information).  If your objective is a domain driven approach, then sure this wouldn't work.  However, not all use cases are so complicated, and this pattern is effective in applications with simple UI-data mappings.  Furthermore, the equality comparison of the entity is straight forward with this approach, because the client Guids and database int Ids are updated on each transaction.

Comment: It seems that you are advocating something like Row Data Gateway, but this would require a series of strongly-typed implementations of your `ICommittable`, which generates more work without reason.  The assertion that it "isn't very object oriented is unfounded", since we know nothing about the underlying model, only about what data is sent from the UI over the HTTP request.  For all we know, the adapter (the web control object) could implement the interface you defined.  It just isn't implemented in a datamodel class because the mappings are simple enough that it is unnecessary.

Comment: @smartcaveman - Correct, looking at the model and below, it would take a lot of work for an already released piece of software where several applications already use the underlying database schema. The answer that you criticise here assumes a blank sheet which so many of us do not have the opportunity to work with. This is a massive issue with the emergent design worldview and it's fashion counterparts such as eXtreme Programming.

Answer (score -2):

If I'm not wrong it's the repository pattern: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html

This is well described in the Evans Domain Driven Design book and has proven to work well under specific circumstances.

Comment: I can't see any reason to classify the described scenario as an implementation of the `Repository` pattern.  Repositories deal with domain models, for which there is none here.  There is a direct communication between the UI and the datastore, which is fundamentally opposed to a domain driven approach.